# How to get list of Containers present in Azure using DataLakeServiceClient in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake

```py
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
            "https", storage_account_name), credential=storage_account_key)
containers = service_client.list_containers() 
for c in containers: 
      print (c.name)
```

But I am Getting an error like this:

```
AttributeError: 'DataLakeServiceClient' object has no attribute 'list_containers'
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
            "https", storage_account_name), credential=storage_account_key)
containers = service_client.list_file_systems() 
for c in containers: 
      print (c.name)
```